# Unfortunately app_name has stopped- Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

First of all I am new to android. I went through many similar question in SO but none of them make sense to me. I can't get my application running. All I see on the emulator is "Unfortunately {app_name} has stopped". Don't know how to fix it.

Here is my Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

LogCat:

> 02-03 01:49:59.255: E/Trace(3815): error opening trace file: No such
>   file or directory (2) 02-03 01:49:59.255: W/Trace(3815): Unexpected
>   value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03 01:49:59.255: W/Trace(3815):
>   Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03 01:49:59.255:
>   W/Trace(3815): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03
>   01:49:59.314: W/Trace(3815): Unexpected value from
>   nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03 01:49:59.314: W/Trace(3815): Unexpected
>   value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03 01:49:59.334: W/Trace(3815):
>   Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03 01:49:59.334:
>   W/Trace(3815): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03
>   01:49:59.334: D/AndroidRuntime(3815): Shutting down VM 02-03
>   01:49:59.334: W/dalvikvm(3815): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0xb2d2e908) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.rupantar/com.example.rupantar.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):     at
>   com.example.rupantar.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:37) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):     at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815):   ... 11 more

Comment: also share MainActivity Activity code to get more help from us

Answer (score 0):

It could be you exceeded the memory allowed by the app.  Do you have a lot of images or inputs in the app? You could try decreasing the amount of memory used.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Answer (score 0):

it is not able to find your activity. check your activity name or any other spelling mistake.
see here in log cat. it is giving null pointer exception

> 02-03 01:49:59.255: E/Trace(3815): error opening trace file: No such
>   file or directory (2) 02-03 01:49:59.255: W/Trace(3815): Unexpected
>   value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03 01:49:59.255: W/Trace(3815):
>   Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03 01:49:59.255:
>   W/Trace(3815): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03
>   01:49:59.314: W/Trace(3815): Unexpected value from
>   nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03 01:49:59.314: W/Trace(3815): Unexpected
>   value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03 01:49:59.334: W/Trace(3815):
>   Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03 01:49:59.334:
>   W/Trace(3815): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 02-03
>   01:49:59.334: D/AndroidRuntime(3815): Shutting down VM 02-03
>   01:49:59.334: W/dalvikvm(3815): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0xb2d2e908) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815): *

### FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-03 01:49:59.364: > E/AndroidRuntime(3815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to > instantiate activity > ComponentInfo{com.example.rupantar/com.example.rupantar.MainActivity}: > java.lang.NullPointerException 02-03 01:49:59.364:

*

> E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   com.example.rupantar.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:37) 02-03
>   01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 02-03 01:49:59.364:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
>   02-03 01:49:59.364: E/AndroidRuntime(3815): ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

`android:name=".MainActivity"`
You should specify the whole class name including package

**Example**

`android:name="com.example.MainActivity"` where `com.example` is your package

Otherwise it cant identify your class

Comment: Post your mainactivity code and full manifest from starting tag